# Не работает полоса прокрутки в виджете Text на Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, tkinter, text, scrollbar

Сделала внутри графического окна с названием win текстовое окно с названием text1. Мне нужно добавить в окно text1 вертикальную полосу прокрутки с названием scrollbar, но полоса не встает куда надо, а появляется в главном окне win (рисунок 1). Если я делаю полосу прокрутки объектом не win, a text1, то полоса встает куда надо, но не работает правильно - подскажите как исправить. Решения найти не могу.

[image: рисунок 1]

Это код программы с scrollbar являющимся объектом win1

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter

win=Tk()
win.title('Konvertor')
win.minsize(width=600, height=600)
win.maxsize(width=600, height=600)

label3 = Label(win, text="Результат работы", height=1, font= "Arial 10", bd=1)
label3.place(relwidth=0.55, relx=0.7, rely=0.14, anchor="center")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(win)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

text1 = Text(win, padx=4)
text1.place(relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.55, relx=0.7, rely=0.16, anchor="n", bordermode=OUTSIDE)

scrollbar['command'] = text1.yview

text1['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

win.mainloop()
```

Это код программы с scrollbar являющимся объектом text1

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter

win=Tk()
win.title('Konvertor')
win.minsize(width=600, height=600)
win.maxsize(width=600, height=600)

label3 = Label(win, text="Результат работы", height=1, font= "Arial 10", bd=1)
label3.place(relwidth=0.55, relx=0.7, rely=0.14, anchor="center")

text1 = Text(win, padx=4)
text1.place(relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.55, relx=0.7, rely=0.16, anchor="n", bordermode=OUTSIDE)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(text1)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

scrollbar['command'] = text1.yview

text1['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

win.mainloop()
```

[image: рисунок 2]

Comment: как понять работает не правильно? Вам нужно чтобы в конкретных ситуациях она появлялась и исчезала? (в плане если текст переходит границы `text` то полоса появлялась?)

Comment: Зажмите Enter в текстовом окне, и увидите, что полоса прокрутки работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zm4B.png

Comment: а почему полоса не выглядит как нормальная полоса? в ней даже бегунка нет. И почему по умолчанию бегунка на ней нет? Чтобы он появился надо Enter оказывается нажать. Так не должно быть

Comment: Полоса прокрутки выглядит как нормальная полоса, когда ей нечего прокручивать (действительно, зачем бегунок, если прокручивать нечего?). Просто большинство текстовых редакторов ее скрывают в этих случаях.